# MongoLab Authorization exception

Tags: windows, mongodb, cloud-hosting, rackspace-cloud, mlab

I created a MongoDB account on MongoLab cloud server and I have a DB created and its empty (no collection, just 1 user) as of now.

this is what the command given at Mongolab to connect to the DB

```
mongo dbh13.mongolab.com:27137/myDB -u <username> -p <password>
```

is the user name here mongolab account credentials or the user i created in the myDB there.? I tried both, it's not authorizing.

but if try to connect to directly with out authorization (from Windows), it worked
with this command

```
mongo dbh13.mongolab.com:27137/myDB
```

but after which if i try to do something like show dbs/show collections it fails with the following message

```
> show dbs
assert failed : listDatabases failed:{
        "assertion" : "unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:38.117.159.162"
,
        "assertionCode" : 10057,
        "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
        "ok" : 0
}
Fri Aug 12 16:30:50 uncaught exception: assert failed : listDatabases failed:{
        "assertion" : "unauthorized db:admin lock type:-1 client:38.117.159.162"
,
        "assertionCode" : 10057,
        "errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
        "ok" : 0
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution for authorization from windows shell

```
> mongo "dbh13.mongolab.com:27137/myDB"
  MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5
  connecting to: dbh13.mongolab.com:27137/myDB

> db.auth("<username>","<password>")
```

http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20177338-i-m-using-the-windows-mongo-shell-and-can-t-connect-help